# Kill unload function in JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to kill the unload function with javascript(jquery)?

I am looking for something like this:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(){
    confirm("Close?")
}
```

or in jquery:

```
$(window).unload(function() {
    confirm("close?")
});
```

Now, on window unload I get my confirm alert but it will continue in any case. Clicking cancel it won't stay on my page.

Comment: But try returning `false` from the jQuery version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the function has to return `false` to abort or `true` to continue, so you cauld simply return the confirm like this:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(){
   return confirm("Close?")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(window).unload(function() {
    var answer = confirm("Leave This website?")
if (answer){
    return false;
}
else{
    alert("Thanks for sticking around!");
    return true;
}
});
```

Comment: This leaves the page either way.. not really what he was asking for (though what he was asking for isn't possible with onunload)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a way. The onbeforeunload function works a bit differently than other events. All you have to do is return a string from the function, and the browser will do the rest of the work for you. The syntax is like this:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function () { 
  return "Close?"; 
}
```

And that's all that you need to do. Clicking "Cancel" in the dialog that comes up will keep the user on the current page, and OK will let the user navigate away or close the page. It's really easy enough that you don't need to use jQuery at all.

Comment: uhh ... no.  I think you mean, `return confirm("Close?");`

Comment: Nope, I meant exactly what I wrote. Though, I suppose I did leave out a little bit. Though it's not a spec event, it is used by most browsers. Feel free to take a look at their reference pages:

Microsoft: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536907%28VS.85%29.aspx
and Mozilla: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onbeforeunload