# How can I make the browser wait until the user has clicked a button on a jQuery dialog box before it leaves the current page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dialog, window

I have this inside my `$(document).ready` function:

```
$(window).unload(function() {
            check_saved();
            });
```

`check_saved()` just triggers a dialog box that asks the user if they would like to save their form data before leaving the page. The browser displays the dialog box but then navigates away instantly. I want the browser to wait until the users clicks a button, just like it would for a normal `alert()`. How do I do this? Also, chrome seems to ignore the unload event? Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate/related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2433625/497356

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How the user navigate to another page? Let say user is doing it by clicking some link on the page. then you can check in that action instead of page unload.

```
$('a').click(function(e){
 if(  check_saved()!=true){

    e.preventDefault();
    return false;   
  }

});
```

Comment: The unload event should be triggered when the user clicks a link, clicks forward or back, closes the window or tries to go to a new page in the address bar. So i would want to have the same result for any of these possibilities

Comment: Then it would be better if you look at the duplicate question ,I think you can find the answer from that .

Comment: by looking at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6063522/jquery-beforeunload id dont think there is anyway you can pause unload, may just have to use  something other than a jquery dialog.